# How to share variables and functions across multiple client side JavaScript files with Webpacker in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Webpacker packs files like so

```
(function(module, exports) {

  function myFunction() {...}
```

a consequence of this is that functions and variables from one file are not accessible from another. Or the console.

What's the "rails way" to address this?

Answer (score 4):

Once you move over to Webpacker, you can write your Javascript with modern ES6. This way, we can export and import modules in conventional ES6.

E.g:

```
// app/javascript/some_module.js

import moment from 'moment';

const SomeModule = {
  someMethod() {
    return someResult;
  }
};

export default SomeModule;
```

And you can now import this into another module:

```
// app/javascript/another_module.js

import SomeModule from './some_module';

SomeModule.someMethod();
```

Notice the folder structure as comments in the file.

Comment: This feels like the right answer. Thank you.

When should I put files in /app/javascript/packs/ vs /app/javascript/ ?

Comment: app/javascript/packs serves as the entry point for webpack to start the compilation process. Hence, it is advised to keep the pack files clean only with minimal code importing the modules and packages and keeping the actual application related code outside of app/javascript/packs.

Whatever lives in the pack directory is compiled in a separate file and can be accessed via `javascript_pack_tag "pack_name"`

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help. "import" still wraps whatever is imported in functions and so functions and variables are not available to each other across imported files.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the required variables/functions as Webpack plugins using `environment.plugins.append` in your `config/webpack/environment.js' file.

So, for example, if you wanted to expose `$` and `jQuery` functions from the jQuery module, the file would look like this:

```
#config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
)
```

Hope it helps!